# Wrong Database time

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have `created_at` and `updated_at` column in my database table, which were created using Laravel migrations `timestamps()`. Now the problem is when I am creating or updating data the times are storing 6 hours ahead of my machine time/timezone.
How can I solve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the timezone in your `config/app.php` file, for instance if you are in Amsterdam (your timezone) your should do this:

```
'timezone' => 'Europe/Amsterdam',
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the timezone line in your config/app.php file.
For instance I get

```
'timezone' => 'Europe/Paris',
```

You must set a PHP compatible timezone, more info here : http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.europe.php